# Celery-Supervisor: How to restart a supervisor job to make newly updated celery-tasks working?

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery, supervisord

I have a running supervisor job for my celery server. Now I need to add a new task to it, but unfortunately my celery server command is not configured to track those dynamic changes automatically.

Here is my celery command:

```
python manage.py celery worker --broker=amqp://username:password@localhost/our_app_vhost
```

To restart my celery process, I have tried,

```
sudo supervisorctl -c /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf restart <process_name>
supervisorctl stop all
supervisorctl start all
service supervisor restart
```

But nothing found working. How to restart it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to manage process with supervisorctl, you should configure supervisorctl, rpcinterface in your configuration file.

Here is a sample configuration file.

**sample.conf**

```
[supervisord]
logfile=/tmp/supervisord.log ; (main log file;default $CWD/supervisord.log)
logfile_maxbytes=50MB        ; (max main logfile bytes b4 rotation;default 50MB)
logfile_backups=10           ; (num of main logfile rotation backups;default 10)
loglevel=info                ; (log level;default info; others: debug,warn,trace)
pidfile=/tmp/supervisord.pid ; (supervisord pidfile;default supervisord.pid)
nodaemon=false               ; (start in foreground if true;default false)
minfds=1024                  ; (min. avail startup file descriptors;default 1024)
minprocs=200                 ; (min. avail process descriptors;default 200)

[program:my_worker]
command = python manage.py celery worker --broker=amqp://username:password@localhost/our_app_vhost

[unix_http_server]
file=/tmp/supervisor.sock   ; (the path to the socket file)

[supervisorctl]
serverurl=unix:///tmp/supervisor.sock ; use a unix:// URL  for a unix socket

[rpcinterface:supervisor]
supervisor.rpcinterface_factory = supervisor.rpcinterface:make_main_rpcinterface
```

Now start supervisor with

```
supervisord -c sample.conf
```

Now if you want to restart your worker you can do it with

```
supervisorctl -c sample.conf restart my_worker
```

This restarts your worker. Alternatively you can also drop to supervisor shell and you can restart it

```
sudo supervisorctl -c sample.conf
supervisor> restart my_worker
my_worker: stopped
my_worker: started
```

**Note:**

There is an option to autoreload workers in Celery

```
python manage.py celery worker --autoreload --broker=amqp://username:password@localhost/our_app_vhost
```

This should be used in development mode only. Using this in production is not recommended.

More about this on [celery docs](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/workers.html#autoreloading).

Answer (score 4):

you can write your celery task in `/etc/supervisor/conf.d/`. create a new config file for celery like `celery.conf`.

Assuming your virtualenv is `venv`, your django project is sample and your celery script is in `_celery.py`

The file should look like

```
[program:celery]
command=/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/venv/bin/celery --app=sample._celery:app worker --loglevel=INFO
directory=/home/ubuntu/sample/
user=ubuntu
numprocs=1
stdout_logfile=/home/ubuntu/logs/celery-worker.log
stderr_logfile=/home/ubuntu/logs/celery-error.log
autostart=true
autorestart=true
startsecs=10

; Need to wait for currently executing tasks to finish at shutdown.
; Increase this if you have very long running tasks.
stopwaitsecs = 600

; When resorting to send SIGKILL to the program to terminate it
; send SIGKILL to its whole process group instead,
; taking care of its children as well.
killasgroup=true

; if rabbitmq is supervised, set its priority higher
; so it starts first
priority=998
```

after writing this supervisor program you need to run

If you add the supervisor program run this
`$ sudo supervisorctl reread`

> celery: available

If you add/update the supervisor program run this
`$ sudo supervisorctl update`

> celery: added process group

To check the status of your celery task
`$ sudo supervisorctl status celery`

> celery                            RUNNING    pid 18020, uptime 0:00:50

To stop the celery task
`$ sudo supervisorctl stop celery`

> celery: stopped

To start the celery task
`$ sudo supervisorctl start celery`

> celery: started

To restart the celery task (this would stop and again start the specified task)
`$ sudo supervisorctl restart celery`

> celery: stopped
>   celery: started

Answer (score 2):

If some task running then restart celery waiting for complete them. So need to kill all running process.
run following command for kill all celery process:

```
kill -9 $(ps aux | grep celery | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}' | tr '\n' ' ') > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Restart celery:

```
sudo supervisorctl stop all
sudo supervisorctl start all
```